# Using dict.get() in mapping values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, mapping

I am following a code in a book, and in the dataframe, I have a column of 30~40 occupations some of which are not provided, and I want to map unprovided occupations to "Not Provided"
So I created a dictionary as below

```
occ_mapping = {'INFORMATION REQUESTED PER BEST EFFORTS' : 'NOT PROVIDED', 'INFORMATION REQUESTED' : 'NOT PROVIDED','INFORMATION REQUESTED (BEST EFFORTS)' : 'NOT PROVIDED','C.E.O.': 'CEO'}
```

Is there difference between the following two codes?

```
f = lambda x: occ_mapping.get(x, x)    
fec.contbr_occupation = fec.contbr_occupation.map(f)
```

and

```
fec.contbr_occupation = fec.contbr_occupation.map(occ_mapping)
```

The book says it uses .get() to allow occupations with no mapping to "pass through", not sure what this means especially if the above codes do the same.

And the variable x refers to the occupation in the dataframe, not dict. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think difference is whats happen if no match key of dictionary in column.

If use `get` with second parameter if no match get same value, because second parameter is `x` (working like `replace`). But if necessary specify another value for not match only specify it in second parameter, check last column in sample data:

```
occ_mapping.get(x, x)
```

If use only `map` if no match is returned missing value.

```
.map(occ_mapping)
```

**Sample**:

```
occ_mapping = {'INFORMATION REQUESTED PER BEST EFFORTS' : 'NOT PROVIDED',
              'INFORMATION REQUESTED' : 'NOT PROVIDED',
              'INFORMATION REQUESTED (BEST EFFORTS)' : 'NOT PROVIDED',
              'C.E.O.': 'CEO'}

fec = pd.DataFrame({'contbr_occupation':['INFORMATION REQUESTED PER BEST EFFORTS',
                                         'SOMETHIG ELSE']})

f = lambda x: occ_mapping.get(x, x)    
fec['contbr_occupation1'] = fec.contbr_occupation.map(f)

fec['contbr_occupation2'] = fec.contbr_occupation.map(occ_mapping)

f = lambda x: occ_mapping.get(x, 'no match')    
fec['contbr_occupation3'] = fec.contbr_occupation.map(f)
print (fec)
                        contbr_occupation contbr_occupation1  \
0  INFORMATION REQUESTED PER BEST EFFORTS       NOT PROVIDED   
1                           SOMETHIG ELSE      SOMETHIG ELSE   

  contbr_occupation2 contbr_occupation3  
0       NOT PROVIDED       NOT PROVIDED  
1                NaN           no match
```